# QGIS ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtSvg'

Tags: qgis, installation, error, ubuntu, pyqt5

Recently, I've installed QGIS 2.99 on my new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

deb http://qgis.org/debian-nightly xenial main

deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-nightly xenial main

```
sudo apt-get update

wget -O - http://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2016.gpg.key | gpg --import

gpg --fingerprint 073D307A618E5811

gpg --export --armor 073D307A618E5811 | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Unfortunately, the processing toolbox is missing and there is an error when launching QGIS:

```
Konnte Erweiterung 'processing' nicht laden

ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtSvg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 313, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 29, in
    from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 38, in
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 56, in
    from processing.modeler.ModelerAlgorithmProvider import ModelerAlgorithmProvider
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/modeler/ModelerAlgorithmProvider.py", line 38, in
    from processing.modeler.EditModelAction import EditModelAction
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/modeler/EditModelAction.py", line 30, in
    from processing.modeler.ModelerDialog import ModelerDialog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/modeler/ModelerDialog.py", line 37, in
    from qgis.PyQt.QtSvg import QSvgGenerator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/QtSvg.py", line 1, in
    from PyQt5.QtSvg import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtSvg'


Python-Version: 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
QGIS-Version: 2.99.0-Master Master, 313ec55

Python-Pfad:
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/benuterzname/.qgis3/python
/home/benuterzname/.qgis3/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python35.zip
/usr/lib/python3.5
/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/home/benuterzname/.qgis3//python
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Currently master is under heavy development and not meant to be used in production

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the python3-pyqt5.qtsvg dependency. Install that and retry.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtsvg` ...Installing the python3-pyqt5.qtsvg dependency was more simple than expected.